# jasmine.stringMatching method is undefined

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html documents the method jasmine.stringMatching(/regex/).  But when I run a test with karma-jasmine, jasmine.stringMathing is undefined.

Does anyone know what I can do to make jasmine.stringMatching available in my tests?

Comment: What `karma-jasmine` version do you have installed? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your version of karma-jasmine is using Jasmine 2? Last time I looked a lot of Jasmine tools weren't up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is about *what `jasmine` version your `karma-jasmine` is using*. [Even the currently latest `karma-jasmine` 0.3.6 is using jasmine-2.1](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/blob/v0.3.6/package.json#L31).

Note that before `karma-jasmine` 0.3, it had its own `jasmine` bundled into the package, but starting with 0.3 it is using the one installed from npm. See this relevant issue:

- [Use Jasmine from NPM](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/7)

Comment: hmmm, karma-jasmine 0.1.6 package.json show no dependency on jasmine itself, so it must contain its own implementation.  That might explain it, because I do have Jasmine 2.3 installed in my node_modules/ dire.

Comment: Ah!  I see that jasmine is never used.  So karma-jasmine must have its own implementation.

Comment: Indeed: node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js

Comment: @lsiden I think the updated answer should clear things up, hope that helps.